# Windows 7 shuts down automatically

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Recently I formatted my system and now I'm running Windows 7. When I keep working my system will shut down every 1 or 2 hours.

Before I was using XP3 and did not have this problem. I face this issue only when I started to use Windows 7 as my OS. Below is my system config, please help me to resolve this problem.

> OS  : Windows 7 Ultimate 32 BIT (ACTIVATED)
>   HD  : 320 GB X 2 Sata
>   Ram : 2 GB DDR2
>   Processor    : AMD Sempron
>   Graphic Card : NVIDIA Geforce 6150SE nForce 430 - 793 MB

Comment: Do you get any warning? Does it shut down nicely or abruptly?
Try looking at the event viewer for any clues.

Comment: I don't get any warning, it will directly shut down even without showing "Windows is shutting down"

Comment: And how about the Event Viewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that Windows is activated this behavior is seen when the Windows is not activated.
If machine is shutting down abruptly check the processor is not over heating.

Comment: Well OP has clearly point out that Windows is activated so its a useless suggestion for him. But yeah about processor you could be right. Also running memtest will be helpful for him.

Comment: @Ramhound in his system specs he clears it `OS : Windows 7 Ultimate 32 BIT (ACTIVATED)`.